# JSTL doesn't work when running from within eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, jstl

I'm trying to add JSTL support to an spring boot application, but I'm getting this error message when running it from **within eclipse**:

```
The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

If i generare an executable war and run it, JSTL works correclty.

I've tried almost all the solutions described in the other questions but none of it seems to focus on running it from eclipse.

I've created this tiny repo to demostrate it:

https://github.com/rroman-encora/brokenjstl

This is my setup:

- Spring Boot 1.5.7
- Eclipse Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)
- JDK 11.0.11
- The project runs with source and target java 1.8

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

If another poor soul finds him self in this situation, may this be the answer:

Just copy all the *.tld files from the jstl jar inside your WEB-INF directory and this should work.

Obviously there's a "proper" way to do this, maybe it's just a setting on spring boot, maybe you need to configure the embedded tomcat/jasper TLD Scanner, but today I'm so tired to keep looking for the perfect aswer.

BTW this also keeps working if you deploy your application as an excecutable war.